# Android Timer is causing random Device time change

Tags: android, timer

I have a strange problem. In my android application I have 10 ms timer running.
after long run(14 hours of run ) any how timer is causing change in device time.

Usually time changes 2 days ahead

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


TextView DateTextView;
TextView BatteryTextView;
String   date;

Thread mUpdateUIThread;

public native  void WatchDogTimeTest();

int[] m_array ; 
Timer mTimerThread;

String StrDdate; 
int n  = 0;

public IntentFilter s_intentFilter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    DateTextView    = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.DatedisplayTxtVw);
    BatteryTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.BatteryStatus);

     date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(new Date());
     DateTextView.setText(date);

     s_intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
     s_intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED);
     s_intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
     s_intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED);
     s_intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED);

     this.registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver,s_intentFilter);

     CreateMutipleThread();
     TimerThread();

     WatchDogTimeTest();
}

public void CreateMutipleThread()
{
 for(int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++)
 {
     mUpdateUIThread= new Thread() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            try {
              while (!isInterrupted()) 
              {
                Thread.sleep(100);   //Check for Aux Battery Status After 10 Second
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                {
                  @Override
                  public void run() 
                  {
                      n++;
                      if(n >= 10000)
                          n= 0;
                  }
                });
              }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           }
          }
        };
        mUpdateUIThread.start();
  }
}

public void TimerThread()
{ 
    mTimerThread = new Timer();
    //Set the schedule function and rate
    mTimerThread.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            StrDdate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(new Date());
        }      
    },1000,1);  
 }

 public void InvalidateTimer()
   {
      this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            printTime();
         }
      });
   }

 public void printTime()
 {

 }


public BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {

        final String action  = intent.getAction();

        //Date Change Broad cast
        if(action.equals(Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED))
        {
             String mydate = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
             date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(new Date());
             DateTextView.setText(date);
             DateTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
             BatteryTextView.setText(mydate);
        }

    }
};
 }
```

Any idea how to solve this problem. This is my Test Code

Comment: Not related to the problem, but may I know why you need to format the date every 10ms? It may have effect on performance issue...

Comment: Andrew this is my real test code. this code has changes the device time in 14 hours of run .